# Resolving the Base-points through Blow-ups

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is related to a question I asked earlier: [Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875782/hesses-pencil-base-points-and-resolution-of-singularities-through-blow-ups)

So, the Hesse pencil is given by $\lambda (x^3+y^3+z^3)+\mu xyz=0$, where $[\lambda,\mu]\in\mathbb{CP^1}$ and $[x,y,z]\in\mathbb{CP^2}$. I can compute the base-points as follows:

Let $x=0$ such that $xyz=0$ (corresponds to the line at infinity). Then, we have $\lambda(y^3+z^3)=0$. Let $\lambda\neq 0$; rescaling yields $\lambda=1$. So, $y^3+z^3=0$. Let $y=1$ such that $z^3=-1$. So, $z=\exp\left(\left(\frac{\pi+2\pi n}{3}\right)i\right)$, $n=0,1,2$. This yields $z=-1,\exp\left(\frac{\pi}{3}i\right),\exp\left(-\frac{\pi}{3}i\right)$. We can introduce $a=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}i\right)$ and rewrite the last two roots as $-a^2$ and $-a$, respectively.

So, the base points are $[0,1,-1]$, $[0,1,-a^2]$ and $[0,1,-a]$. I can repeat this for $y=0$ and $z=0$.

My question is how do I resolve these base-points through blow-ups. For example, what procedure (basically, how to get the ball rolling) do I need to follow to resolve $[0,1,-1]$?

***Edit*** 
As far as the procedure is concerned, an example within this forum is [Example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838106/resolution-of-singularities-base-point/845095#845095).  For this example, base point $[u,v,w]=[0,1,0]$ is transformed to (x,y) coordinates by setting $v=1$ in the homogenized equation and letting $(u,w)=(x,y)$. Subsequently, blow-up of the base-point (x,y)=(0,0) is discussed.

But I do not know how this procedure is applicable to my case and what to do (start-off) with my base-point $[0,1,−1]$. Do I basically consider the chart $x=0$ and consider the curve $y^3+z^3$ with the base-point $(y,z)=(1,−1)$ and proceed to blow this up?

Thanks, Radz.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what you are asking. Do you know how to blow up a point in $\mathbf P^2$? That's all you need to do here.

Comment: Dear @Asal Beag Dubh, If we look at the base point $[0,1,-1]$, we are saying that all level curves pass through this point (right?). What I want to do is remove this intersection through blow-ups; like what happened here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838106/resolution-of-singularities-base-point/845095#845095

Comment: Dear Radz, I understand. I am saying that if you blow up that point, the proper transforms of curves will no longer intersect on the preimage of the point. The proof will be exactly as in the linked question.

Comment: Dear @Asal Beag Dubh, I can follow the argument given in the above mentioned solution, in particular, how the base point $[0,1,0]$ is transformed to $(x,y)$ coordinates and the subsequent blow-up of the base-point $(x,y)=(0,0)$. But I do not know what to do (start-off) with my base-point $[0,1,-1]$. Do I basically consider the chart $x=0$ and consider the curve $y^3+z^3$ with the base-point $(y,z)=(1,-1)$ and proceed to blow this up?