# Blow-up in Projective Space: Choosing the Appropriate Chart

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space, blowup

Consider $x^2+y+\alpha=0$ (made-up example), where $(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}^2$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb C$ is a free parameter. The equation defines a family of curves.

The curves have no common points in the Cartesian plane therefore we consider the complex projective plane $\mathbb{CP}^2$. Homogenizing by using $x=X/Z$ and $y=Y/Z$ yields $X^2+YZ+\alpha Z^2=0$.

The only base point is $[X,Y,Z]=[0,1,0]$ (corresponds to line at infinity). We need to blow-up this base point.

This is the part I do not understand:

In the chart $Y=1$, we have $X^2+Z+\alpha Z^2=0$, which has the base point $(X,Z)=(0,0)$. We then proceed to blow-up this base point in the $XZ$ coordinates.

**Why do we consider the chart $Y=1$. Say, if the base point was $[X,Y,Z]=[0,1,-1]$, which chart do I consider?**

---

**Edit:** Please ignore the following. This has been resolved.

I was thinking about another example: Consider $y-mx=0$, where $m$ is a free parameter. The common point in the Cartesian plane is $(x,y)=(0,0)$. Suppose, we embed the equation in $\mathbb{CP}^2$. Then, $x=X/Z$ and $y=Y/Z$ yields $Y-mX=0$. If $Z=1$ the base points are $[0,0,1]$ and $[1,1,1]$. If $Z=0$ the base point is $[1,0,0]$. But if I apply Bezout's Theorem, then there should be only 1 base points. Why am I getting a total of 3? What is my mistake?

Thanks, Jay.

Comment: Please ignore my comment tagged as edit. I figured it out. For $Z=1$, we have $Y=mX$ such that $[X,Y,Z]=[X,mX,1]=[1,m,1/X]$ (if $X\neq 0)$ and given that it is uniquely determined by $m$, this is not a base point. Within this case we can also have $X=0$ such that $Y=0$; yields the point $[X,Y,Z]=[0,0,1]$ and this is a base point. Finally, if $Z=0$, we basically have the same situation as for the case of $Z=1$. Only possible candidate for a base point is $[X,Y,Z]=[0,0,0]$, but of course this is excluded from $\mathbb{CP}^2$.

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg, I made a mistake. I was adding it as a comment, when you commented. I will update the question.

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg, Thanks. I don't know what I was thinking earlier:-). However, my Chart conundrum still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pencil of curves $x^2+y+\alpha=0$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$ has equation $x^2+yz+\alpha z^2$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$. But then, as you observed, there is a base-point which is $[x:y:z]=[0:1:0]$. This point is on the chart $y=1$, that is why you want to choose this chart to blow-up the point, because blow-up a point of $\mathbb{C}^2$ is easy. But you can also blow-up directly this point of $\mathbb{P}^2$ if you prefer.

In general, you have always one of the three charts $x=1$, $y=1$ or $z=1$ which contains your point and you can make change of coordinates (translations) so that it is the origin.

Comment: Dear @Jeremy Blanc, Thanks. So, for example, if a pencil of curves has a base point $[X,Y,Z]=[0,1,-1]$. Can take the chart $Y=1$ and blow-up the base point $(X,Z)=[0,-1]$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$? Will this make sense?

Comment: Dear @Jérémy Blanc, Did you mean the following for "translations"? If $[X,Y,Z]=[0,1,-1]$ is a base point, I can translate this as $[X,Y,Z+1]=[0,1,0]$ and then in chart $Y=1$ proceed to blow-up $(X,Z+1)=(0,0)$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: Yes. If your point is $[X:Y:Z]=[0:1:-1]$, then take the chart $Y=1$ and parametrize it with $(x,z)\mapsto [x:1:z-1]$ so that now the point is $(0,0)$. This will be easier for the calculations of the blow-up.

Comment: Dear @ Jérémy Blanc, Thanks, Got it.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Hi, You mentioned that the point can be blown-up directly in $\mathbb {P}^2 $. I only know how to blow-up in $\mathbb{C}^2 $. Are there any books that would be worthwhile (without being too abstract) that describes the blow-up process in the projective space? Thanks.

Comment: The blow-up of $[1:0:\dots:0]$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ is, basically by definition, equal to the projection from $X=\{([x_0:\dots:x_n],[y_1:\dots:y_n])\in \mathbb{P}^n\times \mathbb{P}^{n-1}\mid x_iy_j=x_jy_i \mbox{ for }i,j=1\dots n\}$ to $\mathbb{P}^n$. You can check that restricting to the chart containing your point it is what you already know for the blow-up of $\mathbb{C}^n$. This is also done in any text of introduction to algebraic geometry.