# Definition and computation of concrete blow-up on projective plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-space, blowup

I have trouble finding a definition for the blow of of a point on the projective plane (or any projective space), and a projective plane curve. So first of all if you have a reference treating this I would appreciate.
Hartshorne talks about affine varieties or blow-up coherent sheaves of ideals in general on a noetherian scheme but I didn't find anything on the concrete case of a point in a projective space. Gathman briefly says that on any algebraic variety we can consider an open covering of affine schemes, we can blow-up these and glue them. He also says  we can define it to be the closure of the graph $(x,f_1(x),\dots,f_r(x))$ if $f_1,\dots,f_r$ are homogeneous polynomials defining our variety but it's not clear for me what this thing is supposed to be.

In [his last comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878551/blow-up-in-projective-space-choosing-the-appropriate-chart) on his answer Jérémy Blanc defined the blow-up of $\mathbb P^n$ at $[1:0:\dots:0]$ to be
$$X=\{([x_0:\dots:x_n],[y_1:\dots:y_n])\in\mathbb P^n\times\mathbb P^{n-1}\mid x_iy_j=x_jy_i \forall i,j\in[1,n] \}$$ which I guess is a particular case of more general definition where we consider $[1:a_1:\dots:a_n]$.

Now consider the projective curve in $\mathbb P^2_{\mathbb C}$ defined by $f_{\lambda}=y^2z^3-x^5+5\lambda xz^4-4\lambda z^5$ with $\lambda\neq0,1$. It has a singular point at $[0:1:0]$ and so I want to blow it up at this point. I would guess that the total inverse image is
$$\{([x:y:z],[t:u])\mid xu-tz=0,f_{\lambda }(x,y,z)=0\}.$$
Now if as in the affine case I consider the chart $U_t$ we would get $xu-y=0$ but replacing $y$ by $xu$ in $f_{\lambda}$ breaks homogeneity and so $[x:y:z]$ being a root of $f_{\lambda}$ doesn't make sense does it ?

Do we consider charts of $\mathbb P^1,\mathbb P^2$ silmunateously ? That is on the chart $U_x\times U_t$ for example we would get the that the total inverse image is
$$\{([1:y:z],[1:u])\mid (y,z,u)\in V(z-u,y^2z^3-1+5\lambda z^4-4\lambda z^5)\}$$
which I'm not sure of. Is it the correct approach or am I off road ? And how to extract the strict transform from this ?

Finally if for example I consider the chart $\{y\neq 0\}$, I can blow-up as in the affine case. It seems to be enough (and simpler) to do this affine blow-up to characterize the blow up in $\mathbb P^2$, it it the case ?

Comment: You should have a look at p.28 in Hartshorne, where the blow-up of a point is considered. This should answer most of your questions.

Comment: @DamianRössler I will check it right away and I'll tag you if I have questions.

Comment: @DamianRössler Well I guess I have a question, this describes the affine case, not the projective one am I right ? I guess this is showed by just saying that we blow-up at the origin.

Comment: I would consider affine charts on both projective spaces. You will then get an equation for the total transform (as you describe). If the variety you want to blow up is irreducible, this total transform (or rather its restriction to the product of affine charts) will have two irreducible components, one of which is a copy of affine space. The other one is the blow up. You then get the whole blow up by looking at all the combinations of affine charts. Also, for computational purposes, I would first apply an automorphism of projective space to move the point you blow up to $[1:0\dots:0]$.

Comment: @DamianRössler So in the example $U_x\times U_t$ what would the two components be ? As I said it's not so clear to me.

Answer (score 3):

In the chart $D(y)\subset \Bbb P^2$, your curve is cut out by $z^3-x^5+5\lambda xz^4-4\lambda z^5$. The blowup of $(0,0)\in \Bbb A^2\cong D(y)$ (= $[0:1:0]$ in $\Bbb P^2$) is covered by two charts, $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,z,t]/(tx-z)$ and $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,z,u]/(x-zu)$, with the maps to $\Bbb A^2=\operatorname{Spec} k[x,z]$ given by the spectrum of the natural maps $k[x,z]\to k[x,z,t]/(xt-z)$ and $k[x,z]\to k[x,z,u]/(x-zu)$.

To calculate the inverse image of your curve under these maps, you can substitute $z=xt$ in one chart and $x=zu$ in the other in to the equation $z^3-x^5+5\lambda xz^4-4\lambda z^5$ to get $$x^3t^3-x^5+5\lambda x^5t^4-4\lambda x^4t^4=x^3(t^3-x^2+5\lambda x^2t^4-4\lambda xt^4),$$ $$z^3-z^5u^5+5\lambda z^5u - 4\lambda z^5 = z^3(1-z^2u^5+5\lambda z^2u - 4\lambda z^2)$$ as equations of the total transform in each chart. To get the strict transform, remove the factor of $x^3$ or $z^3$ corresponding to the exceptional divisor so that you're left with the equations in the parentheses. Note that since $z=0,u=0$ is not a solution to the second equation of the strict transform, the strict transform is completely contained in the first chart.

Comment: So here we first reduce ourselves to an "affine" blow-up by considering the chart $D(y)$. If I understand correctly in the end the total transform is $\{([x:1:z],[1:t])\mid \text{your first equation} \}\cup \{([x:1:z],[u:1])\mid \text{your second equation} \}$, is it correct ? I feel like I'm misunderstanding something, why would we always have middle term 1 (for me it comes from the fact that we restrict the curve to $D(y)$ ) ?

Comment: The total transform also includes what happens on the charts $D(x)$ and $D(z)$, but since the blowup doesn't change anything in those charts, people usually don't mention them. Do note that I said "equations of the total transform in each chart", so I'm also omitting the discussion of those charts.

Comment: So on $D(x)$ for example, the curve doesn't pass through $[0:1:0]$, so $D(x)\cap C$ should be isomorphic to $\{([1:y:z],[u:t])\mid t-uz, f_{\lambda}=0\}$ and in this case we must have $t\neq 0$. For $D(z)$ we get $\{([x:y:1],[u:t])\mid u=xt,f_{\lambda}=0\}$. Taking the union of these with the union in my previous comment would then be the total transform right ?

Comment: I think you have some bigger issues here - $[0:1:0]\notin D(x)$, so the blowup map is an isomorphism over $D(x)$. Your descriptions in that previous don't really make sense (why do you insist $t\neq 0$? that's not necessary). $\Bbb P^2$ can be covered by three affine opens, $D(x),D(y),D(z)$. Over $D(x)$ and $D(z)$, the blowup map is an isomorphism, so their preimages are covered by one affine open each, and over $D(y)$, the preimage of the blowup can be covered by two affine opens (as detailed in my post).

Comment: I don't insist $t\neq 0$ I just noted that in this case it's contained in an affine open, which would be $U_x\times U_t$. Indeed I believe that we have no choice but to have $t\neq 0$, $t=0$ seems to lead to contradictions. To me seems to go with what you're saying. Moreover why would my descriptions not this makes sense. Here the element $[1:y:z]$ is sent to $([1:y:z],[1:z])$ (we can consider $[1:z]=[t:tz]$ precisely because $t\neq 0$) and vice versa. I understand that there are isomorphisms for $D(x),D(z)$ but how would you write them (or one of them) explicitly ?